# Why does calling axios.post in a loop result in 500 status code error?

Tags: node.js, api, axios, request

This is my code which is being called on loop (asynchronously):

```
  try {
       await axios.post(REWARDS_POST_URL, userReward, { maxContentLength: Infinity, maxBodyLength: Infinity, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } });
       console.log(':::( COMPLETED ):::');
       return true;
     } catch (e) {
       logger.debug(null, JSON.stringify(e.response.data));
            return false;
     }
```

The success_status is totally random. Like this:

```
:::( COMPLETED ):::
Success status:  true
[2022-01-10T17:55:17.846] [DEBUG] main-app - [null]: {"error":{"http_code":50
0,"code":102,"message":"Something went wrong","internal":{"id":"cky8n7t7c005g
0mtk5olc8awe","code":102,"message":"Something went wrong"}}}
Success status:  false
[2022-01-10T17:55:18.589] [DEBUG] main-app - [null]: {"error":{"http_code":50
0,"code":102,"message":"Something went wrong","internal":{"id":"cky8n7t7n005h
0mtkf642yj56","code":102,"message":"Something went wrong"}}}
Success status:  false
[2022-01-10T17:55:18.594] [DEBUG] main-app - [null]: {"error":{"http_code":50
0,"code":102,"message":"Something went wrong","internal":{"id":"cky8n7t8l005i
0mtkbzwonccq","code":102,"message":"Something went wrong"}}}
Success status:  false
:::( COMPLETED ):::
Success status:  true
[2022-01-10T17:55:36.347] [DEBUG] main-app - [null]: {"error":{"http_code":50
0,"code":102,"message":"Something went wrong","internal":{"id":"cky8n8284005p
0mtkkdnwlf5y","code":102,"message":"Something went wrong"}}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are there any functions that are encapsulating the try method??

Comment: probably something wrong with the endpoint